# Named Credentials, AuthProvider response comes as authentication error

Tags: salesforce, apex

created  Auth provider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC8Ar.png)
used that auth provider in named credentials
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsk5R.png)
When we do save in named credentials it will throw authentication error
AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=unauthorized_client
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDhw.png)

Whether I have to enable any settings